# Как оптимизировать эту строчку?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Вот строка из парсера с использованием BeautifulSoup.

```
song_page_ref = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'page', 'class': 'site'}).find('div', attrs={'class': 'entry-title'}).find('a').attrs['href']
```

Как сделать её более минималистичной и читаемой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не пытаться все уместить в одну строку, а разбить на отдельные этапы поиска, каждый в отдельной строке, что-то такого типа:

```
site_page = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'page', 'class': 'site'})
entry_title = site_page.find('div', attrs={'class': 'entry-title'})
song_page_ref = entry_title.find('a').attrs['href']
```